# Assign Securables to Role using TSQL

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have create a role in my SQL 2008r2 and I now I need to assign number of securables to it (like stored procedures and views).
Is there any TSQL command in order to do that? 
Please excuse my expressions (in case there are not the right one) in this case. 
I don't know if I'm using the right one.

Comment: The sql commands will start with "grant".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Stored Procedures and scalar-valued functions

```
GRANT  EXECUTE ON [dbo].[<Object>] TO <Role>
```

For Tables, views, and table-valued functions. You can specify any or all of the options used in this example.

```
GRANT  SELECT,INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE ON [dbo].[<TABLE>] TO <Role>
```

Additionally, you can deny and revoke

```
DENY   EXECUTE ON [dbo].[<Object>] TO <Role>
REVOKE EXECUTE ON [dbo].[<Object>] TO <Role>
```